# Lightswitch 2013 Linq queries to Get min value

Tags: linq, aggregation, lightswitch-2013

I'm writing a timesheet application (Silverlight) and I'm completely stuck on getting linq queries working. I'm netw to linq and I just read, and did many examples from, a Linq book, including Linq to Objects, linq to SQl and linq to Entities.(I assume, but am not 100% sure that the latter is what Lightswitch uses). I plan to study a LOT more Linq, but just need to get this one query working.

So I have an entity called Items which lists every item in a job and it's serial no

So: Job.ID int, ID int, SerialNo long

I also have a Timesheets entity that contains shift dates, job no and start and end serial no produced

So Job.ID int, ShiftDate date, Shift int, StartNo long, EndNo long

When the user select a job from an autocomplete box, I want to look up the MAX(SerialNo) for that job in the timesheets entity. If that is null (i.e. none have been produced), I want to lookup the MIN(SerialNo) from the Items entity for that job (i.e. what's the first serial no they should produce)

I realize I need a first or default and need to specify the MIN(SerialNo) from Items as a default.

My Timesheet screen uses TimesheetProperty as it's datasource

I tried the following just to get the MAX(SerialNo) from Timesheets entity:

```
var maxSerialNo =
            (from ts in this.DataWorkspace.SQLData.Timesheets
             where ts.Job.ID == this.TimesheetProperty.Job.ID
             select ts.StartNo).Min();
```

but I get the following errors:

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataServiceQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

'Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataServiceQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Min' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Min(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

I also don't get why I can't use this:

```
var maxSerialNo = this.DataWorkspace.SQLData.Timesheets.Min(ts => ts.StartNo);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDataServiceQueryable` doesn't support full set of LINQ operator like `IEnumerable` has.

> **IDataServiceQueryable** – This is a LightSwitch-specific type that allows a restricted set of “LINQ-like” operators that are remote-able to the middle-tier and ultimately issued to the database server. This interface is the core of the LightSwitch query programming model. IDataServiceQueryable has a member to execute the query, which returns results that are IEnumerable. [[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/10/03/advanced-lightswitch-writing-queries-in-lightswitch-code.aspx?Redirected=true)]

Possible solution is, execute your query first to get collection of type `IEnumerable` by calling `.ToList()`, then you can call `.Min()` against the first query result. But that isn't good idea if you have large amount of data, because `.ToList()` will retrieve all data match the query and do further processing in client side, which is inefficient.

Another way is, change your query using only operators supported by `IDataServiceQueryable` to avoid retrieving unnecessary data to client. For example, to get minimum `StartNo` you can try to use `orderby descending` then get the first data instead of using `.Min()` operator :

```
var minStartNo = 
            (
                 from ts in this.DataWorkspace.SQLData.Timesheets 
                 where ts.Job.ID == this.TimesheetProperty.Job.ID
                 orderby ts.StartNo descending select ts
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```